# Lefties have rights too!

Tags: halacha, handedness

There are many Halachos that a leftie does with his left hand and those that he does with his right hand. For example Shema is always done with the right hand even if you are a leftie. By which other Halachos does a leftie use his right hand too?

Comment: I Love the play on words

Comment: I take exception to the careful construction of the sentence that avoids ending it in a preposition, and thus allows the writer to employ the Jewish 'by'!

Comment: Counterpart: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30662

Answer (score 8):

R' Paysach Krohn wrote an English-language book on halachos for lefties. It's available free by mail if you call his home; he lives in Queens, New York, and is listed. (Obviously, you might want to pay him for it, and the postage.) The book is arranged in sections, one of which is a list of things lefties do the same as righties, and another of which is things lefties do the opposite from the way righties do; so one whole section of that book answers your question. (I'd copy things therefrom, but can't locate my copy.)

*Edit:* I've now discovered [this book online](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0Byx6sZjO1KzmOTI1ZWU1ZTItZmQ2ZC00ZmNmLWJhMDAtMWY2MTlhYTcyOGU1). (Thanks to [Dr. Melech Tanen](https://docs.google.com/Doc?docid=0ASx6sZjO1KzmZDhwbW5jal8xZndoOHJuZ3Q) for linking to it.) He has twenty-one subsections devoted to things lefties do with the right side, of which the following are about the right hand specifically (as sought in the question):

- Cover your eyes with your right hand for *sh'ma*.
- Give *tz'daka* using your right hand.
- Bless a child on Friday night by putting your right hand on his head.
- Tap your chest with your right hand during confession.
- Put on your right sleeve before your left when dressing.
- Pick up the cup with your right hand for washing hands on arising.
- Pour water over your right hand first, when washing hands on arising or for bread.
- When holding onto a *sefer Tora* with one hand for an *aliya*, use the right hand.
- When doing *birchas kohanim*, your right hand should be slightly above your left.
- Look at your right-hand fingernails during *havdala*.

As always, for practical *halacha*, consult your rabbi.

Comment: It is called "Yad Eliezer". Rav Chaim Kanievsky wrote a guide for lefties called "Kuntres Ish Itar"

Comment: Re banging the left side of your chest, that may have more to do with [where your heart is](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44765/what-side-does-someone-with-situs-inversus-bang) than what hand you use. ;)

Answer (score 3):

This [chart](http://www.scribd.com/doc/3137280/Itur-Yad-Halacha-for-Lefthanded-People) is pretty interesting.

Comment: Please edit in the contents of the link.