# Halachic Differences between lefties and righties

Tags: halacha, handedness

What are the halachic differences between left-handed people and right-handed people?

For example, Tefilin are put on right arm for lefties and left arm for righties.

Can someone provide a comprehensive list of the common differences?

Comment: just found a chart here by Tzvi's answer http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3359/lefties-have-rights-too

Comment: "a comprehensive list of the common differences"? Is taht even possible?

Comment: Counterpart: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3359

Answer (score 6):

R' Paysach Krohn wrote an English-language book on halachos for lefties. It's available free by mail if you call his home; he lives in Queens, New York, and is listed. (Obviously, you might want to pay him for it, and the postage.) It's also [online](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0Byx6sZjO1KzmOTI1ZWU1ZTItZmQ2ZC00ZmNmLWJhMDAtMWY2MTlhYTcyOGU1). (Thanks to [Dr. Melech Tanen](https://docs.google.com/Doc?docid=0ASx6sZjO1KzmZDhwbW5jal8xZndoOHJuZ3Q) for linking to it.)

The book is arranged in sections, one of which is a list of things lefties do the same as righties, and another of which is things lefties do the opposite from the way righties do; so one whole section of that book answers your question. It contains fourteen subsections:

- A left-handed person holds a food or *mitzva* item in his left hand while saying the *b'racha* on it;
- some say that's true of a cup of wine held during *birchas hamazon* also;
- it's true of the *lulav* also.
- A *kidushin* ring is given by the left hand of a left-handed bridegroom, and/or to the left hand of a left-handed bride. (See the book for exceptions.)
- A left-handed person steps back after *sh'mone esre* starting with his right foot;
- take a *sefer Tora* with his left hand;
- and possibly hold the chicken for *kaparos* with his left hand.
- It's unclear whether he should burn *chametz* (and do similar activities (see the book)) with his left hand.
- A left-handed man wears his *t'fila shel yad* on his right arm,
- removes his *t'fila shel rosh* with his right hand,
- and puts his *shel yad* on the left side of his *t'filin* pouch.
- A left-handed *sofer* uses his left hand to write.
- A left-handed man wearing *t'filin* does *n'filas apayim* on the arm without *t'filin*: the left.
- A left-handed person ties his right shoe before the left one, and unties it after the left one.

But consult your own rabbi for practical rulings.

Comment: Here is the above file by R' Paysach Krohn in better formatting to print. [You can find it here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RyJT9w86vnzx7FFG11-XSENP1Q1vE_RK/view?usp=sharing) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RyJT9w86vnzx7FFG11-XSENP1Q1vE_RK/view?usp=sharing