# Someone losing their dominant arm

Tags: halacha, handedness

There are some [practical differences between righties and lefties](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30662/5459) in halacha. What happens if someone loses their dominant arm? Do they gain the halachic status of being dominant with their other arm or not? For example while a left handed sofer can write tefillin with their left hand, a righty cannot. If a right handed sofer lost his right arm, and taught himself to write with his left hand, would he be allowed to write tefillin with his left hand?

Comment: ידכה בה''י זו שמאל אחרים אומרים ידך לרבות את הגידם תניא אידך אין לו זרוע פטור מן התפילין אחרים אומר ידכה לרבות את הגידם