# Would it be more appropriate to beat the *center* of one's chest on Yom Kippur instead of the left, since that's where the heart is actually located?

Tags: yom-kippur

Our hearts are located in the middle of our chests and extend slightly to the left side. I'm sure each person does as s/he sees fit, but siddurim often instruct us to beat the left side. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: I think when they say "left side" they mean "center leaning to the left."

Comment: Even better https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44765/759

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What side does someone with Situs inversus bang](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44765/what-side-does-someone-with-situs-inversus-bang)

Answer (score 3):

My wife heard a drasha from a chasidic source that may apply. The left side is considered din and the right side is considered Rachamim. By banging on the left side of the chest we are "suppressing" din and asking for rachamim.

I checked the Art Scroll machzor, the Art Scroll daily (Hebrew only and with translation), and the Koren (Rabbi Sacks) daily siddurim. They all say

"Bang the left side of the chest with the right hand."

Apparently they hold that it does not involve where the heart is located.